# How to create a user defined datatype in c as asked below?

Tags: c

can any one guide me how to create a datatype in C programming which can add 2 numbers in the range of -2^127 to (2^127)-1  ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So, what do you think? How big should this data type be?

Comment: If you haven't done it yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What are you even trying to calculate ?!

Comment: gcc haves [__int128_t](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As the range contains negative integers we need a signed number. The largest signed integer that the C standard specifies
is the long long int (introduced in the ISO C99 standard, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).

The standard stipulates that it should be able to at least hold
numbers in the range -(2^63 - 1) to 2^63 - 1. Note here that the common way of implementing this data type in
hardware is to use a 64-bit two's complemented integer that gives the exact range of -2^63 to 2^63-1. This is too small
for your needs so you'll either need to use a non-standard datatype or create your own.

Luckily there is a 128 bit
signed integer datatype in both the gcc and the clang compilers. It is called __int128_t. I couldn't find any specification
on the range of this type but we can assume it in practice to be -2^127 to 2^127-1. This datatype can handle
addition in the range you specify except when carry occurs (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic)).